# Wiremock- Verifying unique JSON matches expected?

Tags: java, json, http, wiremock

I'm trying to test my REST application which generates some JSON and uses it to contact another API. I want to ensure the correct JSON is being generated, but the problem is that two of the fields are unique for each run, specifically an ID and a timestamp.

How can I verify this JSON is correct using Wiremock given that the fields are unique each time? Is there a way I can leave those fields to "any" or something in Wiremock?

`obj.verfyObjContaining("{\"id\": 123 ,\"timestamp\": 11:11:11}");`

Timestamp and ID are unique so this doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Setting them to any isn't your only option. You can also mock the timestamp and id. Setting them to a static value during the test run. The advantage of that would be that you at least test that the value is being pushed out with the api call.

Unfortunately without any code posted I can not give more details than that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it! Found a "matching()" verification function in Wiremock which takes a regex.